# Sparse vectors aggregation with ActivePivot

Tags: java, vector, aggregate-functions, activepivot

In our ActivePivot project we aggregate large vectors of simulated data (the length of the vectors can reach one million values) and the memory consumption is very high.

Most of the time, most of the values in the vectors are zero. Can ActivePivot leverage that to compress the vectors? Can we still aggregate the compressed vectors?

Answer (score 2):

ActivePivot will not automagically detect that the vectors you aggregate are sparse and apply some compression mechanism, but as ActivePivot is object based, you can write your own aggregation function, that will aggregate compressed vectors (or any other kind of data you want actually).

Now if you need an example of zero-based vector compression here is a simple one:

```
/*
 * (C) Quartet FS 2013
 * ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. This material is the CONFIDENTIAL and PROPRIETARY
 * property of Quartet Financial Systems Limited. Any unauthorized use,
 * reproduction or transfer of this material is strictly prohibited
 */
package com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.aggfun.impl;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.quartetfs.fwk.IClone;

/**
 * 
 * Vector of primitive doubles, compressed by zero-elimination.
 * 
 * @author Quartet FS
 *
 */
public class DoubleVector implements IClone<DoubleVector> {

    /** Underlying data */
    protected final double[] data;

    /** Private internal constructor */
    private DoubleVector(double[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Create a compressed vector from a raw vector.
     * 
     * @param raw
     * @return compressed vector
     */
    public static DoubleVector compress(double[] raw) {
        final int length = raw.length;

        // How many 64-bits slots do we need to mark all of our values?
        int bucketCount = 0;
        while((bucketCount << 6) < length) { bucketCount++; }

        // Count non-zeroes
        int nonZeroes = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            nonZeroes += raw[i] == 0.0 ? 0 : 1;
        }

        // Initialize the data structure:
        //  - one slot to store the size of the final vector
        //  - n bits packed in buckets to mark zeroes and non-zeroes
        //  - the non-zero doubles
        final double[] data = new double[1 + bucketCount + nonZeroes];
        data[0] = Double.longBitsToDouble((long) length);

        // Mark and copy the non-zeroes
        nonZeroes = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < bucketCount; b++) {

            // Clear bucket
            data[1 + b] = Double.longBitsToDouble(0L);

            final int from = b << 6;
            final int to = Math.min(length, (b+1) << 6);
            for(int i = from; i < to; i++) {
                double value = raw[i];
                if(value != 0.0) {
                    // Mark the non-zero value and copy the value
                    int bucketIdx = i >>> 6;
                    int shift = i & 0x3F; // Keep 6 bits
                    final long bit = 1L << shift;

                    long bucket = Double.doubleToLongBits(data[1 + bucketIdx]);
                    bucket = bucket | bit;
                    data[1 + bucketIdx] = Double.longBitsToDouble(bucket);

                    // Copy the value
                    data[1 + bucketCount + nonZeroes++] = value;
                }
            }
        }

        return new DoubleVector(data);
    }

    /** Deep clone implementation */
    public DoubleVector clone() {
        return new DoubleVector(data.clone());
    }

    public int length() {
        return (int) Double.doubleToLongBits(data[0]);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Add this vector to another vector, then return the result.
     * 
     * @param vector
     * @return sum vector
     */
    public DoubleVector add(DoubleVector other) {
        return add(other, false);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Add this vector to another vector, then return the result.
     * 
     * @param vector
     * @param negative if true, the vector is actually subtracted
     * @return sum vector
     */
    public DoubleVector add(DoubleVector other, boolean negative) {

        final int length = (int) Double.doubleToLongBits(this.data[0]);
        if((int) Double.doubleToLongBits(other.data[0]) != length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot aggregate vectors of different lengths.");
        }


        // How many 64-bits slots do we need to mark all of our values?
        int bucketCount = 0;
        while((bucketCount << 6) < length) { bucketCount++; }

        // How many non-zeroes does the result bear?
        // (we do not try to detect new zeroes caused by the sum)
        int nonZeroes = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < bucketCount; b++) {
            nonZeroes += Long.bitCount(Double.doubleToLongBits(this.data[1 + b]) | Double.doubleToLongBits(other.data[1 + b]));
        }

        // Allocate the data of the result
        final double[] result = new double[1 + bucketCount + nonZeroes];
        result[0] = Double.longBitsToDouble(length);
        for(int b = 0; b < bucketCount; b++) {
            result[1 + b] = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(this.data[1 + b]) | Double.doubleToLongBits(other.data[1 + b]));
        }

        // Loop on both vectors, and sum
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            final int bucketIdx = i >>> 6;
            final int shift = i & 0x3F;  // Keep 6 bits
            final long bucketA = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.data[bucketIdx + 1]);
            final long bucketB = Double.doubleToLongBits(other.data[bucketIdx + 1]);

            long bitA = (bucketA >>> shift) & 0x1L;
            long bitB = (bucketB >>> shift) & 0x1L;

            double valueA = bitA == 0L ? 0.0 : this.data[1 + bucketCount + a++];
            double valueB = bitB == 0L ? 0.0 : other.data[1 + bucketCount + b++];
            if(bitA != 0L || bitB != 0L) {
                result[1 + bucketCount + c++] = valueA + (negative ? -valueB : valueB);
            }
        }

        return new DoubleVector(result);
    }


    /**
     * @return the decoded content of the vector
     */
    public double[] content() {

        // How many 64-bits slots do we need to mark all of our values?
        final int length = (int) Double.doubleToLongBits(data[0]);
        int bucketCount = 0;
        while((bucketCount << 6) < length) { bucketCount++; }


        final double[] content = new double[length];

        int nonZeroes = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            final int bucketIdx = i >>> 6;
            final int shift = i & 0x3F;  // Keep 6 bits
            final long bucket = Double.doubleToLongBits(data[bucketIdx + 1]);

            if(((bucket >>> shift) & 0x1L) != 0L) {
                // The bit is set, this is a non-zero value
                content[i] = data[1 + bucketCount + nonZeroes++];
            }

        }

        return content;
    }

    /** @return the compression ratio as a percentage */
    public double compressionRatio() {
        long originalSize = 16L + 8 * Double.doubleToLongBits(data[0]);
        long compressedSize = 16L + 8L + 16L + 8 * data.length;

        return 0.01 * (100L * compressedSize / originalSize);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(content());
    }


    /** Useful helper method that can be used from the debugger */
    protected static String binaryString(final long b) {
        final String binary = Long.toBinaryString(b);
        final int length = binary.length();
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if(binary.length() <= 64) {
            for(int i = 0; i < (64 - length); i++) { buffer.append('0'); }
            buffer.append(binary);
            return buffer.toString();
        } else {
            return binary.substring(length - 64);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Some test.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] v1 = new double[] { 0.0,   0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0 };
        double[] v2 = new double[] { 10.0, 10.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0 };
        double[] sum = v1.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) { sum[i] += v2[i]; }
        DoubleVector c1 = DoubleVector.compress(v1);
        DoubleVector c2 = DoubleVector.compress(v2);
        DoubleVector cSum = c1.add(c2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v1)  + " -> " + c1   + " (" + c1.compressionRatio()   * 100 + "%)");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v2)  + " -> " + c2   + " (" + c2.compressionRatio()   * 100 + "%)");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum) + " -> " + cSum + " (" + cSum.compressionRatio() * 100 + "%)");
    }

}
```

And here is the base code to aggregate those with an ActivePivot aggregation function:

```
/*
 * (C) Quartet FS 2013
 * ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. This material is the CONFIDENTIAL and PROPRIETARY
 * property of Quartet Financial Systems Limited. Any unauthorized use,
 * reproduction or transfer of this material is strictly prohibited
 */
package com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.aggfun.impl;

import com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetPluginValue;

/**
 * Aggregation function that sums compressed vectors of doubles.
 * 
 * @author Quartet FS
 *
 */
@QuartetPluginValue(interfaceName = "com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.aggfun.IAggregationFunction")
public class DoubleVectorSum extends GenericAggregationFunction<DoubleVector, DoubleVector> {

    /** serialVersionUID */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11699698472584733L;

    public DoubleVectorSum() {
        super("VectorSum");
    }

    @Override
    public String description() { return "Function to sum compressed double vectors"; }

    @Override
    protected DoubleVector aggregate(boolean removal, DoubleVector aggregate, DoubleVector input) {
        return aggregate.add(input, removal);
    }

    @Override
    protected DoubleVector merge(boolean removal, DoubleVector main, DoubleVector contribution) {
        return main.add(contribution, removal);
    }

    @Override
    protected DoubleVector cloneAggregate(DoubleVector aggregate) {
        return aggregate.clone();
    }

}
```